# I have a kotlin Gif decorder code but I want this code to be written in java

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, gif

I'm working on GIF decoder. The code is working fine. Only think I'm totally new to kotlin so not able to understand the syntax used in. So I'm totally lost. Help me to write this same code in Java. i want this code to be used in main activity(Java). But the current code is wrote for Fragments in Kotlin.

And this library used https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Code:

```
class GifDecoderFragment : BaseFragment(), CoroutineScope {
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    private var frames = emptyList<Bitmap>()
    private var durations = emptyList<Int>()

    private var currentFrameIndex = 0

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.decoder, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val frames = mutableListOf<Bitmap>()
            val durations = mutableListOf<Int>()
            val decoder = GifDecoder(InputSource.ResourcesSource(resources, R.drawable.room3))

            for (i in 0 until decoder.numberOfFrames) {
                val frame = Bitmap.createBitmap(decoder.width, decoder.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                decoder.seekToFrame(i, frame)

                Log.d("BaseActivityneww", "onCreate: $i")

                frames += frame
                durations += decoder.getFrameDuration(i)


            }
            decoder.recycle()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                this@GifDecoderFragment.frames = frames
                this@GifDecoderFragment.durations = durations

                if (isAdded) {
                    startAnimation()
                    decoderLoadingTextView.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (frames.isNotEmpty()) {
            startAnimation()
        }
    }

    private fun startAnimation() {
        decoderImageView.setImageBitmap(frames[currentFrameIndex])


        launch {
            delay(durations[currentFrameIndex].toLong())
            advanceAnimation()
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        job.cancelChildren()
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        job.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun advanceAnimation() {
        currentFrameIndex++

        currentFrameIndex %= frames.size
decoderImageView.setImageBitmap(frames[currentFrameIndex])

launch {
            delay(durations[currentFrameIndex].toLong())
            advanceAnimation()
        }
    }
```

Xml:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/decoderImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

Comment: That code is using coroutines, which is a kotlin-specific feature, so you won't be able to code the exact same behaviour in Java

Comment: Ooh...so is any other option to do it?

Comment: Based on another answer here on stackoverflow it seems like Kotlin compiler performs some kind of transformation to coroutines, so I guess there's no easy way to do the same in Java

Comment: ohk...but the main library used is wrote in java. This link to https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Comment: Yes, my point was that you can't convert the exact code to Java, but on the other hand you don't need to do the exact same thing. That code is first extracting frames and durations from a GIF resource and then it's playing the animation by changing the visible frame after some delay. It's just using coroutines to avoid freezing the main thread, but in Java you can use a new thread

Comment: yaa bro you are right. is it possible for you to code it java and show me.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the Android SDK installed on my machine, so I can't really use that library

Comment: it's ohk bro thanks...i will give a try

Answer (score 1):

you can use The Kotlin plugin if you're using Android Studio:

> Menu > Tools > Kotlin -> Decompile Kotlin to Java.

Comment: yaa i have updated to latest plug-in...but still it's disabled.

Comment: What is your Android Studio version?

Comment: android studio version is 3.3.1

Comment: Please  refer to this link blog.safedk.com/technology/hello-kotlin-convert-android-project-part-1/

Comment: this din help me